# Coldfusion Fusebox URL-Controller SES mappings

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox, fusebox, fw1

just starting to use coldfusion & fusebox a bit (this is my second question asked here, where a lot of the response mentioned that fusebox is no longer supported and there are possibly better suited frameworks - so am looking at ColdBox and FW/1 - but still wanted to ask this Fusebox question!).

I am trying to understand if Fusebox 5.5 (the latest version, which  am using) supports any kind of convention based url mapping. I have the noxml skeleton app which starts and runs on the urL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8500/noxml
```

Now I have seen that this defaults to executing the welcome function within the app controller - what I want to know is if there is convention based url mapping built in so i can define my urls like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8500/noxml/app/welcome
```

(e.g. {appname}/{controllername}/{functionname})

I have also seen this question: [How do I create Search Engine Safe URLs in Fusebox 5.1 noxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744181/how-do-i-create-search-engine-safe-urls-in-fusebox-5-1-noxml) and having added the suggested basic config:

```
FUSEBOX_PARAMETERS.queryStringStart = "/";
FUSEBOX_PARAMETERS.queryStringSeparator = "/";
FUSEBOX_PARAMETERS.queryStringEqual = "/
```

I can hit this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8500/intranet/index.cfm/fuseaction/app.welcome
```

but obviously, thats still a pretty ugly url..

Is what I want even possible out of the box with fusebox 5.5? (documentation and community links on the fusebox site 404..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the purest form of SES URLs (http://site.com/controller/action) , it requires the removal of the index.cfm which involves having to do some URL rewriting on the web server side. No framework that I know of can avoid URL rewriting if you want to remove the index.cfm

IIS7.5 supports it natively using the web.config or using built-in wizards; Apache has mod_rewrite via .htaccess. There are 3rd party products for IIS6/7.

If you want more power/control, you can also check out using coldcourse (http://coldcourse.riaforge.org) as mentioned here:

[How do I create Search Engine Safe URLs in Fusebox 5.1 noxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744181/how-do-i-create-search-engine-safe-urls-in-fusebox-5-1-noxml)

As the poster mentions, apparently there is built in URL rewriting in FB 5.5 but I'm not familiar with 5.5 intimately.

Comment: Ok thanks. And if I didn't mind the index.cfm but wanted to use inex.cfm/controller/action could I do that easily?